# How can I send the request to the Managed Bean using javascript ?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this Primefaces code,

```
<p:commandButton id="btnDisplay" styleClass="btn" value="Display Selected" 
      update="messages" style="margin:20px 0 20px 0;" 
      actionListener="#{jobsTree.displaySelectedMultiple}" />
```

I have to perform the same action using javascript instead of using `h:commandbutton` like

```
<input type="button" />
```

How can I send the request to the Managed Bean using javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

As you are using primefaces you can use `p:remoteCommand`:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="displaySelected" update="messages"  
                 actionListener="#{jobsTree.displaySelectedMultiple}"/>
```

To call it from JS just use:

```
displaySelected();
```